# Excluding entry point from compilation in Webpack 2

Tags: javascript, svg, webpack, webpack-2

In my webpack.config.js file I have several js and svg entry points:

```
entry: {
        scripts: './src/js/app.js',
        vendor: ['vue', 'axios'],
        svg: glob.sync('./src/img/svg/*.svg')
},
```

And for my svg's I'm using sprite loader:

```
module: {
    rules: [
        ...
        {
            test: /\.svg$/,
            use: [
                {
                    loader: 'svg-sprite-loader',
                    // include: path.resolve('./src/img/svg'),
                    options: {
                        extract: true,
                        spriteFilename: 'img/sprite.svg'
                    }
                }
            ],
        }
    ]
},
```

But the problem is that when I'm compiling in my js folder renders svg.js file. How can I make webpack work so, that svg.js in not be rendered.

Comment: For clarification on what you're trying to do - are you attempting to use the plugin to output a single sprite sheet at `img/sprite.svg` from all the sprites in `src/img/svg/*.svg`?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: By omitting the `svg` entry point does it not work as expected? Does that not generate a sprite sheet of the SVGs you use in your application and are loaded by webpack?

Comment: It I ommit that entry point my sprite wouldn't be compiled.

Comment: Can you update your question with some examples of how you load your SVGs into your application?

Answer (score 2):

Add a tiny plugin to your webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    {
      apply: (compiler) => {
        compiler.plugin('emit', (compilation, callback) => {
          delete compilation.assets['svg.js'];
          callback();
        });
      }
    }
  ]
};
```